# how can I deploy two contracts

Tags: contract-development

for example,

```
contract A{   

}  
contract B{

}
```

but here contract B will call contract A, I use solidity to compile and get two source code, how can I deployed it? deploy two times on myetherwallet since i have two codes? if I deploy two times, there will be no way to tell B where A is so B cannot find A?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can do like this

1. deploy contract A
2. modify code of contract B to pass the address of contract A in the constructor of contract B
3. deploy the contract B

then you can call contract A from contract B

Answer (score 0):

I updated the answer.

Here is an example I just did for you in Remix IDE

I call them Parent and Child for B and A;

My parent contract deploys the child and then I can access its functions and internal variables.

[image]

Comment: This is different. In OP's example, contract A and contract B do not inherit from each other. Therefore, OP has to deploy both contract A and contract B like Ha ĐANG described

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to deploy both contract one at a time. You can deploy contract B and deploy contract A by executing contract code. Here is sample:

```
contract A {
    constructor(){}
  //your code here  
}

contract B{
    address public address_of_contract_A;
    constructor (){
    A addr_of_a = new A();
    address_of_contract_A = addr_of_a;
    }
    //your code here
}
```

here `addr_of_a` holds the address of just deployed contract, contract address of contract A.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example :

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract A {
    function functionInsideA() public {}
}

contract B {
    A contractA;

    constructor(A _addressOfA) {
        contractA = _addressOfA;
    }

    function callFunctionInsideA() public {
        contractA.functionInsideA();
    }
}
```

It will require you to give the address where you deployed A when deploying B. Then you will be able to call visible functions from A directely in B.